# Removing identical element from all pages of a pdf

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a pdf file with a text box at the bottom of each page that I'd like to remove. Is there a way to automate this process in acrobat or a similar program?

Comment: What version of Acrobat are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the objects are organized inside the PDF.

[image: Adobe Acrobat XI, Tools, Edit Object]

Sometimes for Acrobat XI, you can first try:

- Tools, Content, Edit Object.
- Select your object
- Delete It

Other times, you may need to do this before you can delete:

- Tools, Protection, Mark for Redaction
- Mark your text or objects to redact
- Apply Redactions
- Then Edit Object, select, and then delete

In terms of automation, you can attempt to create an Action Wizard to automate some steps. I am not a programmer, so I could never consistently select the objects I needed to delete.

So, my hacky solution is to use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and utilize the AutoScriptWriter to create one loop of selecting the object, deleting it, and going to the next page.

[image: AutoScriptWriter]

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but it works for me.